# Woocommerce Plug-in: Woocommerce Category Banner - Add Category banner to single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using the plug-in `Woocommerce Category Banner`, I am able to insert a banner image onto each woocommerce category page (though the plug-ins added banner field on the woocommerce category page in the back end).

I am trying to find a way to insert the category banner image on the single product pages (1 level up).

This is the code used to display the category banner (I've included it on `/theme/woocommerce.php`):

```
//Retreives and print the category banner

global $woocommerce;
global $wp_query;

// Make sure this is a product category page
if ( is_product_category() ) {

    $cat_id = $wp_query->queried_object->term_id;
    $term_options = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$cat_id" ); 

    // Ge the banner image id
    if ( $term_options['banner_url_id'] != '' )
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_options['banner_url_id'] ); 

    // Exit if the image url doesn't exist
    if ( !isset( $url ) or $url == false )
        return;

    // Get the banner link if it exists
    if ( $term_options['banner_link'] != '' )
        $link = $term_options['banner_link'];

    // Print Output
    if ( isset( $link ) )
        echo "<a href='" . $link . "'>"; 

    if ( $url != false ) 
        echo "<img src='" . $url . "' class='category_banner_image' />";

    if ( isset( $link ) )
        echo "</a>";
}
```

Using this code I found on here directly after the above code, I am able to insert the category thumbnail on single product pages:

```
elseif ( is_product() ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        echo '<img class="category_banner_image" src="'.$image.'">';
}
```

Any ideas on how to modify either blocks of code to pull the "banner_url_id", that the woocommerce category banner plug-in adds to each category, and insert on a single product page?

Answer (score 0):

the url of the image is stored in wp_option table, so you need to put this in content-single-product.php:

```
$cat_id = $wp_query->queried_object->term_id;
$term_options = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$cat_id" );

$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_options['banner_url_id'] );

if ( $url != false ) 
    echo "<img src='" . $url . "' class='category_banner_image' />";
```

EDIT:

If you want to get banners inside content_single_product.php you need to think in this: every product can be associate to many terms (Like: red, blue, white, etc), so you need to select a random image assosiated to each category, right?

```
 $termArray =  array();
 $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, "product_cat");

 //insert id's in to array
 foreach ($terms as $id) {
    $termArray[] = $id->term_id;
 }

//get random id
$randomId = array_rand($termArray);

 //final ID
$cat_id = $termArray[$randomId];

$term_options = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$cat_id" );

$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_options['banner_url_id'] );

if ( $url != false ) 
   echo "<img src='" . $url . "' class='category_banner_image' />";
```

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply. I copied over the content-single-product.php to "theme/woocommerce/" and added the above code. It didn't appear to do anything. It doesn't look like you changed anything in the code, should it simply work after being moved to the new .php page? I should have mentioned this before, the plugin doesn't include a "category banner" on the individual products page in the back end. I need to pull the 'banner_url_id' from the category the product is placed in.